# Runtime.exec doesn't compile java file

Tags: java, compilation, runtime.exec

I compile java file by Runtime.exec("javac MyFrog.java");
It says no errors, doesn't output anything, but doesn't create MyFrog.class file.
if i write Runtime.exec("javac") it outputs to output some help text.
So I understand that program is working, but don't create class file. Permissions are ok.

Comment: Did you try `javac -verbose`?

Answer (score 2):

`javac -verbose` should give you lot more information, specifically the directory where the file is created. Since you are able to recognize output help text without any parameters, I assume you are capturing the process's stderr and assume you are doing the same for stdout as well (though javac does not seem to write anything to stdout).

Where are you checking for the existence of the .class file? It is created in the same directory as the .java file. If MyFrog.java has a package declaration it will *not* be created in the package sub-dir; for that you have to use `-d` argument.

Comment: run:
0
[parsing started MyFrog.java]
[parsing completed 19ms]
[search path for source files: .]
[search path for class files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/resources.jar,... and it is continued showing class files.]
[total 171ms]

Comment: Which means it is still creating `.class` files. You need to wait for it complete. Use `Process.waitFor()`. BTW Are you reading the Process output and error in a loop? You need to.

Comment: I do waitFor. I read an error stream and output stream.
If i specify wrong filename it gives me an error

Comment: For wrong filename it will complete quickly. If `waitFor` returns and you have printed everything you got on `System.err` then it would either have the location of created class file or some error messages. Post your code, run it on command line and post the output.

Comment: I realized it was problem of NetBeans.
I made it in simple file and it succeed.

Comment: It can't be a NetBeans problem, must be something you were not doing right.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `MyFrog.java` is present in working directory

Comment: javac without parameter and javac <missing file>.java would both print to stderr. If he is able to see error output from one he should be able to see it from another?

Answer (score 0):

Try `javac -verbose` and make sure your classpath is set correct.

Comment: I wrote about -verbose in my comment, with a bad classpath he will get an error output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec() method to create new process,

```
String []cmd={"javac","Foo.java"};

Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
proc.waitFor();
```

Or use ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb =  new ProcessBuilder("javac.exe","-verbose", "Foo.java");

pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();

InputStream inp=p.getInputStream();
int no=inp.read();
while(no!=-1)
{
 System.out.print((char)no);
 no=inp.read();
}
```

Comment: Why? Does the environment need to be changed to call javac?

Comment: @HemalPandya - Sorry! It was my mistake.

Comment: I still don't see how any of this can address the issue, given that he is able to see the output from just `javac`.

Comment: @HemalPandya  - The standard output of Runtime.exec is not automatically redirected the standard output of the caller. One must have to set stream of System.setOut() method.

Comment: You mean standard **error** is not redirected **to** the standard output? Yes, but that is if he is using ProcessBuilder. He is not using it, he is using Runtime.exec, where they have to be read separately. Since OP saw error messages he must be doing that right. In any case, I don't think we will ever know, @ardakshalkar seems much less interested in this issue than you and I.

Answer (score 0):

I always find [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) resource answers all questions about Java exec.